# finding if Javascript function has a closure

Tags: javascript, reflection, closures

Is there a way to find if given function reference has a closure and eventually to access to closed variables? I was searching for something similiar to "arguments" property, but in vain.

**Edit** : outside or inside given function

Comment: Are you asking if you can detect a closure at runtime (e.g., by some runtime state query), or if by examining the code, it is possible to spot where closures might be produced?

Comment: @IraBaxter runtime. Doing code analysis for that seems huge overkill for me

Comment: It may seem like huge overkill, unless you have another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you will never know. That's why closures are used to emulate private members, since you never know what's inside, hence "private".